# NgFor not being passed an array

Tags: json, angular

Ive tried searching for a solution to this, but I cant find anything less than 3 or 4 years old and those dont map to my problem well. I know what the issue is from the error, but cant seem to track it down, although I general idea that I will note in my description below:

I need to generate a menu from an array of json elements in the following format:

```
{
    "body": [{
        "coursename": "introto1",
        "course-lesson-name": "Welcome to One! "
    }, {
        "coursename": "introto2",
        "course-lesson-name": "What is One?"
    }, {
        "coursename": "introto2",
        "course-lesson-name": "What Can We do with One?"
    }]
}
```

This response is coming from AWS API gateway and I have set up the following service to handle the call:

**menus.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MenusService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getLinks(){
      return this.http.get('api address');
  }  
}
```

Here is the component that uses the services:

**navigation.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  MenusService } from './../menus.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  links;
  constructor(private menusService: MenusService,) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.links = this.menusService.getLinks();
  }

}
```

and here is the component view:

**navigation.component.html**

```
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let links of links | async">
        <a>{{links['course-lesson-name']}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I suspect my issue is in the service and the way Im establishing the get call:

```
return this.http.get('api address');
```

What am I missing here?

Here is the error for reference:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. 
NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet `this.links` resolves into an object and not an array.

Do this in your `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.links = this.menusService.getLinks();
    this.links.subscribe(data => console.log(data)); // ensure data here is an array and not an object with `{ body: [....] }`
  }
```

If it is an object like mentioned previously, in your service, try:

```
getLinks(){
      return this.http.get('api address').pipe(
        map(res => res.body),
      );
}
```

You can also do that in the component level too but just be sure to get a handle on the array and not on the object for the `*ngFor`.